# I am trying to do HTML and PHP to load and save a text file to the server

Tags: php, html

desired sequence:

> SaveButton
>      LoadButton
>      When the "load button" is pressed, load a textfile from the server into a textbox.
>      Allow the user to add text
>      When the "save button" is pressed, save the textbox text to the server.

I am having issues with callbacks not executing.

I am worried about the callbacks, I know how to save a file.

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="1" onClick="reply_click(id)">Load</button>
<button id="2" onClick="reply_click(id)">Save</button>
<?php
function reply_click($clicked_id)
{
    echo "hello ";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried to reproduce but my answer routine is not executing.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code before we can hope to debug your callbacks.

Comment: You should connect the callbacks to the buttons.

Comment: and the code you have is ???????

Comment: Can you show some code (not pseudocode) please?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing JavaScript and PHP.

PHP is figured out and executed by the server. Then the web page is sent to the client. Then the user can interact with the page using JavaScript.

You'll have to change the `onClick` events to use AJAX that send a request to a PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to handle AJAX requests without having to mess with low-level things like XMLHttpRequest.